# Display data at jsp after receiving from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am setting these two array's data in an ArrayList and sending this array list from servlet to jsp but on jsp page when i try to print these names and contacts only last name and contact is printed three times. i don't know that mistake is on server side or on client side.

```
    SetsAndGetsData tutor = new SetsAndGetsData();
                List<SetsAndGetsData> alltutors = new ArrayList<SetsAndGetsData>();

                String Names[3] = {"Alpha","Beta","Gemma"};
                String contacts[3] = {"Contact_1","Contact_2","Contact_3"};

                tutor.setNames(n);
                tutor.setContact(contact);
                alltutors.add(tutor);

                request.setAttribute("tutors", alltutors);
                RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Test.jsp");
                req.forward(request, response);

                //Jsp side code  Test.jsp

                <%
                List<SetsAndGetsData> alltutors = (ArrayList<SetsAndGetsData>)request.getAttribute("tutors");
                for(SetsAndGetsData t: alltutors){
                %>
                    <h1><%=t.getname() %></h1>
                    <h1><%=t.getcontact() %></h1>
                    <% } %>
```

Comment: here only the name is shown with no first/last differentiator

Comment: i want to show all three names and three contact so how i should do this please

Comment: Yr code looks fine, as per your requirement. Where are you getting different output